# What do symbols <$> and <*> mean in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

What do the symbols `<$>` and `<*>` mean?

Also, I find some information about `<$` and `$>`.

Comment: Google isn't the right engine for searching symbols in general (there's [Symbolhound](http://symbolhound.com/?q=Haskell+%3C%24%3E)... though, I can't get it to give me any results right now), and Haskell in particular, for it has [two](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%3C%24%3E) excellent [search engines](http://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/?query=%3C%24%3E) of its own, which would have pointed you to the definition right away.

Comment: Ever heard of hoogle? https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%3C$%3E

Comment: @AJFarmar, yeah, now I know this service.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These operators are defined in `Control.Applicative`.  The `<$>` operator is just an infix version of `fmap`:

```
f <$> a = fmap f a
```

And `<*>` is part of the `Applicative` typeclass definition:

```
class Functor f => Applicative f where
    pure :: a -> f a
    (<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

You can search for Haskell functions and operators more easily with [Hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org/).

The `Applicative` typeclass come in between `Functor` and `Monad`:

```
class Functor where ...

class Functor f => Applicative f where ...

class Applicative m => Monad m where ...
```

(Note that this is relationship between `Applicative` and `Monad` only enforced in the recently released GHC 7.10)

Applicatives are structures that follow specific rules.  It's more powerful than a functor but less powerful than a monad.  Specifically a functor can only apply a single-argument function to values in a structure, returning a new structure that contains new values but not a new shape.  The canonical example is `fmap (+1) [1,2,3] == [2,3,4]`, the length of the input list is always the same as the output list.  With applicatives, you can apply a multi-argument pure function across multiple structures:

```
> (+) <$> [1, 2, 3] <*> [10, 20]
[11, 21, 12, 22, 13, 23]
```

The output list's length (its "shape") depends on the lengths of the input lists.  However, something to note is that the length of the output list does not depend on the *values* inside the list.  This is the power that monads add to this hierarchy:

```
> print $ do a <- [1, 2, 3]; b <- replicate a 10; return (a + b)
[11, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13]
```

Here we are combining two structures together, one of which has a "shape" that depends on the values in the other.  This is not possible with just applicatives, and it's the reason why monads are so ubiquitous in Haskell.  However, since every `Monad` is an `Applicative` and every `Applicative` a `Functor`, you still have access to all these tool when working with `Monad`s.

Comment: Is that supposed to be `[1, 2, 3]` in the final example?

Comment: @SebastianRedl It was supposed to be `1` and not `a`, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Denis No problem!  I will say that it took me quite a while to grok applicatives, they're kind of a weird area between functors and monads that has some nuances which aren't immediately obvious.  At this point I would encourage you to try to learn more about applicatives through the popular parsec or attoparsec libraries, both of which rely heavily on applicative operators.  While they're important to know how to use, it's certainly possible to get by without them for quite a lot of cases.  Most people will prefer `<$>` over `fmap`, though, so expect to see that a lot.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that `(+) <$> [1,2,3]` is in fact `[(1+), (2+), (3+)]`.

Answer (score 4):

`<$>` is a synonymous of fmap, `<$>` is the infix operator. It usually used in the context of an applicative functor.

```
import Control.Applicative ((<$>)

-- (<$>), fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b

example1 :: (Int -> Int) -> Maybe Int -> Maybe Int
example1 f g = f <$> g  -- f `fmap` (Just x) = Just (f x)
                        -- f `fmap` Nothing  = Nothing
```

On the other hand the `<*>` is useful when you have a function in the context of a functor and you want to apply that to some value in a another functor context, for instance:

```
example2:: Maybe (Int -> Int) -> Maybe Int -> Maybe Int
example2 f g = f <*> g -- (Just f) <*> (Just x) = Just ( f x)
                       -- Nothing  <*> (Just x ) = Nothing
                       -- (Just f) <*> Nothing   = Nothing
                       -- Nothing <*>  Nothing   = Nothing
```

It can be pictured as an operator that applies a function and simultaneously takes into account the context in which the function is applied.

These operators lift the values and functions to the context of the Functor in which the operations are carry out.